# SVG not appearing in Firefox when using transform and visibility CSS properties

Tags: css, firefox, svg

Please see Codepen https://codepen.io/timbarden/pen/XWrBxev

This is a stripped-down version of the issue. The `visibility` property is being used to allow the cursor to hover the shape only. When the `transform` property is applied the SVG disappears in Firefox. Works all fine in Chrome and even IE. Was built into a site back in 2017 and all was fine, but this issue has since arisen. When the `transform` property is applied the SVG disappears in Firefox.

I've tried will-change: transform but aside from redoing the whole module I'm stuck as to what to change.

Comment: use svg transfrom instead of css transform

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `visibility: hidden;` you may use `pointer-events:none;` for `.item__slice` and `pointer-events: all;`for the `.item__slice--shape`. 
It would be interesting to see a more advanced demo to understand what exactly you want to achieve.

```css
.item__slice {
  fill: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events:none;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(1em);
          transform: translateX(1em);

}
.item__slice--shape {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">
  <symbol id="icon_slice" viewBox="0 0 163.76 189.41"><path d="M163.76,94.55,0,0V189.41a190.31,190.31,0,0,0,133.75-56,192.62,192.62,0,0,0,29.94-38.71Z"/></symbol>
</svg>
  
<svg class="item__slice icon--slice">
 <use class="item__slice--shape" href='#icon_slice' x='0' y='0'/>
</svg>
```